# How to achieve the following multitenancy with apartment gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, apartment-gem

I have an application which is used for hotel booking. It has 3 sections, 1for normal users to search hotels and book rooms. Another for super admin to login and create hotel details. And 3rd will be a saas application for hotel owners to login and check their bookings and income. 
The hotel owners account will be in subdomain.xxxxx.com (subdomain will change for each hotel owner). I have a User and Hotel model, How can I develop a multitenant app so that these models will be common in all the 3sections? According to apartment gem, I have to make the models global. If I make hotel model global, how can I restrict it to multitenancy? Any tutorials and guides would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 models

1. User (roles: user, admin)
2. Hotel

You can create another model "HotelAccount" which will be excluded form the multi-tenant to contain the information you want to access from the public domain.